# string.replace() outputs me an error when defining it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im getting data from an API. Then i want to replace the value in the string from "True" to "Online".

```
request = requests.get("https://api.cleanvoice.ru/ts3/?address=xxxxxxxxxxx")
request_text = request.text
data = json.loads(request_text)
status = data["can_connect"]

onoff = status.replace("True","Online")
```

The error i get from replace() is `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'`

I want to implement a Teamspeak Online Checker by getting the value if the server is online of some russian api. That by the way, works perfectly fine.

Im working on Python 3.7.6

Comment: Try `str(status).replace("True","Online")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `status` variable appears to be a boolean one, as evidenced by the error:

> AttributeError: ***'bool'*** object has no attribute 'replace'

You therefore should be able to just use something like:

```
onoff = "online" if status else "offline"
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot that the value is a boolean value so i just added a if statement like [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) wrote.

```
if status is True:
    print('Its online')
elif status is False:
    print('Its offline')
```

Comment: you don't need an explicit `elif` statement. you can use `else`. and you can use `if status:`

Comment: im gonna add a else at the end so if the Value is not true or false, it print an error.
maybe if the api is offline or something.